# Links do not redirect to Jquery Tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect, jquery-tabs

I have 4 links as

```
<li><a class="open-tab" href="#sirkethesaptab">Şirket Hesabı</a></li>
<li><a class="open-tab" href="#musterihesaptab">Müşteri Hesabı</a></li>
<li><a class="open-tab" href="#odemetab">Ödemeler</a></li>
<li><a class="open-tab" href="#harcamatab">Harcamalar</a></li>
<li><a class="open-tab" href="#personeltab">Personel</a></li>
```

And i have a Jquery tab

```
<div class="col-sm-9 padding-right">
    <div id="tab-container2" class='tab-container'>
        <ul class='etabs'>
            <li class='tab'><a href="#sirkethesaptab">Şirket Hesabı</a></li>
            <li class='tab'><a href="#musterihesaptab">Müşteri Hesabı</a></li>
            <li class='tab'><a href="#odemetab">Ödemeler</a></li>
            <li class='tab'><a href="#harcamatab">Harcamalar</a></li>
            <li class='tab'><a href="#personeltab">Personel</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class='panel-container'>
            <div id="sirkethesaptab">
                <h2>sirkethesaptab</h2>
            </div>
            <div id="musterihesaptab">
                <h2>musterihesaptab</h2>
            </div>
            <div id="odemetab">
                <h2>odemetab</h2>
            </div>
            <div id="harcamatab">
                <h2>harcamatab</h2>
            </div>
            <div id="personeltab">
                <h2>personeltab</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Jquery Codes

```
$('#tab-container2').tabs({
    active: $.cookie('activetab'),
    activate: function (event, ui) {
        $.cookie('activetab', ui.newTab.index(), {
            expires: 10
        });
    }
});

$('.open-tab').click(function (event) {
    var tab = $(this).attr('href');
    alert(tab);
    $('tab-container2').tabs('select', tab);
});
```

I want to redirect to necessary tab when i click to these external links above and when i click to any of these links, browser's adress bar changes but there is no redirection. How can fix this problem ? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What UI version are you using?

Comment: Can you post your css?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it's a silly mistake I guess as you have a missing `#` in your selector within the `.open-tab` click function.

```
$('.open-tab').click(function (event) {
    var tab = $(this).attr('href');
    alert(tab);
    $('#tab-container2').tabs('select', tab); // <- added #
});
```

[**-Demo-**](http://jsfiddle.net/lshettyl/vrne1yoc/)

Note: The `select` option has been removed from jQuery UI v1.10+. You must use `.tabs('active', <tabIndex>)` if at all you plan to use 1.10+

[**-Demo-**](http://jsfiddle.net/lshettyl/vrne1yoc/1/) for 1.10+

Comment: I already put a # to code, nothing changed. Better check my UI version

Answer (score 0):

I have prepared this plunker it seems it is working fine:

"http://plnkr.co/edit/I5HCJasIl7OVEci7cwvI"

Inside the plunkr I placed the last `<div>` at the bottom just to check if page navigates there and it is working fine.

Moreover you must use **name** attribute to an element inside div. Refer the link for the same "http://www.htmlgoodies.com/tutorials/getting_started/article.php/3479511"